# Powershell Script error "Cannot find an overload for "LoadFromCollection" and the argument count: "1"."

Tags: c#, powershell, epplus

I am trying to load an collection object using LoadfromCollection into an excel file. I am using EPPLUS library to do so. But I keep on receiving the error "**Cannot find an overload for "LoadFromCollection" and the argument count: "1"**." Since I am a newbie to PowerShell, not sure how to resolve the issue. Also, is there any other way around to load collection object using EPPLUS library?

```
$pkg = [OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage]::new($Path)
$ws  = $pkg | Add-WorkSheet -WorkSheetname 'test'

$DemoData = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$DemoData = 1..10 | Foreach-Object{

        $BookID = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 1000
        $Date = (Get-Date).adddays(-$BookID)

        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Name = "Book$_"
            BookID = $BookID
            Date = $Date
        } | Select Name, BookID, Date
    }
$null = $ws.Cells['A1'].LoadFromCollection($DemoData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`.LoadFromCollection`](https://documentation.help/OfficeOpenXML/f9ba612b-d47c-4ce9-6bcc-638317c69ac1.htm) is a *generic* method** with the following signature:

```
public ExcelRangeBase LoadFromCollection<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> Collection
)
```

In order for PowerShell to be able to call a generic method, it must be able to *infer* the concrete type `T` of the elements of the `IEnumerable<T>` instance.

Therefore, **given that your `$DemoData` array is *not strongly typed*** - it is of type `[object[]`, PowerShell's regular array type - **PowerShell cannot find a suitable `.LoadFromCollection` method overload**, resulting in the error you saw.

(Note that your `$DemoData = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` statement has no effect: the subsequent `$DemoData = 1..10 ...` statement overrides it, and assigns whatever the command returns, which is an `[object[]]` array.)

The immediate fix would be to ensure that you use a *strongly typed* array, which would mean: `[pscustomobject[]] $DemoData = 1..10 ...`, given that `[pscustomobject]` is the type of the objects that the `Select-Object` call returns.

This *may* be enough, depending on what reflection approach(es) the method uses to determine the input objects' properties:

- *If* it is capable of discovering the properties via the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface, which `[pscustomobject]` implements, then the `[pscustomobject[]]` type constraint is enough.
- If *not*, you'll have to create a regular .NET type via a (PSv5+) *custom class*, as shown below:

```
# PowerShell v5 and above.

$pkg = [OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage]::new($Path)
$ws  = $pkg | Add-WorkSheet -WorkSheetname 'test'

# Define a custom class with the properties of interest.
class Custom {
  [string]   $Name
  [int]      $BookID
  [datetime] $Date
}

[Custom[]] $DemoData = 1..10 | Foreach-Object{

  $BookID = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 1000
  $Date = (Get-Date).adddays(-$BookID)

  # Create and output a [Custom] instance with the specified property values.
  [Custom] @{ Name = "Book$_"; BookId = $BookID; Date = $Date }

}

# Call .LoadFromCollection with the strongly typed array.
$null = $ws.Cells['A1'].LoadFromCollection($DemoData)
```